# How do I log results from an Azure Function App dependency?

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I have an Azure Function App project with the following files:

**Startup.cs**: Registers a dependency

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyLoggingFunction.Startup))]

namespace MyLoggingFunction
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddScoped<MyService>();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyService.cs**: Writes a log message

```
namespace MyLoggingFunction
{
    public class MyService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyService> logger;

        public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public void Go()
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation("MyService.Go");
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFunction.cs**: The actual function; uses `MyService`

```
namespace MyLoggingFunction
{
    public class MyFunction
    {
        private readonly MyService myService;

        public MyFunction(MyService myService)
        {
            this.myService = myService;
        }

        [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
        public IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            this.myService.Go();
            log.LogInformation("All done");
            return new OkObjectResult("Done.");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output visible in Azure after the function runs successfully. Note that the log message from the injected dependency is missing:

[image: log messages]

How do I get log messages from the dependency to show up as part of the built-in logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add logging level entry to host.json :

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must whitelist the classes and/or namespaces from which you want to allow logging. An example `hosts.json` file:

```
{
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "MyLoggingFunction": "Information"
    }
  },
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

This is [documented as an issue on the azure-function-host GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4425).